# having problem installing web3 with pip installer (cytoolz error)

Tags: python, web3py

I'm hving trouble with pip install web3 using python3.10 on a macOS bigsur 11.6

says Building wheel for cytoolz error

I have already tried the following:

- xcode-select --install
- running virtual environment
- bumping down to python3.7 (worked for others)

any more new things to try?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Instead of _describing_ the error, please _show it to us_, in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

I tried

```
pip install cython
```

and

```
 pip install cytoolz
```

got it to

```
pip install web3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Python 3.10.0. I downgraded to Python3.9.7 and was able to build cytoolz wheel and eth-brownie installation worked!